# - Binary Tree Puzzle - Draw tree from these traversals:

Tags: tree, binary-tree, inorder, preorder

Inorder: S A E U Y Q R P D F K L M

Preorder: F A S Q Y E U P R D K L M

[image: This is what I came up with until now.]

I'm pretty confused about what to do with the middle part. No combination seems to work, help? Does anyone have tricks? How do I approach this? I've been smacking my head on this for 2 hours.

I must restore the tree.

Comment: What do you want is to restore the tree given the preorder and inorder traversals?

Comment: Yes basically. and I can't find the rest of the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct result is

[image: your concrete result]

I will try to provide you a general explanation instead of a concrete one for your example. I think it is more useful and after all you could test the algorithm with your concrete case, see that the algorithm works and understand better.

You could think the problem in a recursive way.

In order to facilitate the problem, we could agree on some variables

- `preorder`: an array containing the preorder traversal
- `inorder`: an array containing the inorder traversal
- `l_p`: left index in the `preorder` array
- `r_p`: right index in the `preorder` array
- `l_i`: left index in the `inorder` array
- `r_i`: right index in the `inorder` array

In your concrete example, the first instance would be `l_p = l_i = 0` and `r_p = r_i = 12`.

This could facilitate the explanation:

```
index     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
preorder: F A S Q Y E U P R D  K  L  M
inorder:  S A E U Y Q R P D F  K  L  M
          <      left     > ^   < right >
                            |
                      this is the root
```

A very important fact is to realize that the root of current tree is always `preorder[l_p]`, which the first time is `F`. Now, you must identify the left and right branches of the tree, which are clearly distinguished in the `inorder` array (see diagram above). In order to know that, you search in the `inorder` array the index containing the root `F`; this index is `9`. We can see that the root is at nine places after `l_i`. Let `i` a variable that says how many positions respect to `l_i` is the root of the tree.

So, the keys of left tree are in `inorder` array between `0` and `8`, and the keys of the right tree are between `10` and `12`.

In order to recursively build the left tree you have `l_p = l_p + 1`, because you have already seen the root, and `r_ p = l_p + i =`, but the array `inorder` is delimited by `l_i = 0` and `r_i = l_i + i - 1 =8`.

In the same way, the right tree is in `preorder` between `l_p = l_p + i + 1 = 10` and `r_p = r_p = 12`, while in the array `inorder` it is between `l_i = l_i + i + 1` and `r_i`.

With all this (a little complicated) we could sketch out an algorithm:

```
Node * build_tree(int preorder[], int l_p, int r_p,
                  int inorder[], int l_i, int r_i)
{
  if (l_p > r_p)
    return nullptr; // empty tree

  Node * root = new Node;
  root->key = preorder[l_p];

  int i = 0; // now we search index of preorder[l_p] in inorder array
  for (int j = l_i; j <= r_i; ++j)
    if (inorder[j] == preorder[l_p])
      {
        i = j - l_i; // the root is at l_i + i
        break; // always breaks if everything is ok
      }

  root->left = build_tree(preorder, l_p + 1, l_p + i, 
                          inorder, l_i, l_i + (i - 1));
  root->right = build_tree(preorder, l_p + i + 1, r_p, 
                           inorder, l_i + i + 1, r_i);
  return root;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) This is an amazing answer.